# how to get location name if i have latitude and longitude in Yahoo Maps

Tags: api, maps, yahoo

I am designing a web application which will use Google Maps and Yahoo Maps. But I am searching for yahoo api to get location address using lat and long. Google Api is not working properly. They have very close limitations. Please help me..!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried, you should use the "Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)" feature of the Google Geocoding API.

Details here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

If you have tried that and aren't satisfied, you should check out Yahoo's Place Finder API. That let's you search for addresses by passing lat/long coordinates. See links below:

Overview: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/requests-pf.html
Passing lat/long: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/address-formats.html#latitude-longitude

Comment: Sir, I have already used Google Api for this. As I mentioned in my question, Google applies limitation which are not sufficient for me. So I want to go with Yahoo Maps. Please tell me how to use Yahoo Api for address from lat long

Comment: Yahoo PlaceFinder API has been deprecated, and Yahoo no longer provides it as a geocoding or reverse geocoding service. Yahoo has transitioned to using the HERE Location Services for geocoding-related features.